# Maximum Number of Files in a Single Directory for Netapp NFS mounts on Linux

Tags: linux, nfs, netapp

On an older Linux box I have, there is an NFS mount of a Netapp.  Once there are 100k files in a single directory on this box, files can no longer be written.  Anyone know what might be causing this?  I have been told symbolic links can still be written.

I will add more specific information as I look it up.  Please, skip the 'use a better a file / folder structure and/or database', I know ...

Comment: 2.6.9-55.0.12.ELsmp

Comment: Maybe hitting the wafl.maxdirsize limit, going to try ot replicate issue and then will see

Comment: Looks like it might be that there is a 100,000 hard link limit, and these files are directories: http://now.netapp.com/NOW/cgi-bin/bol?Type=Detail&Display=292410

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system is hitting the link limit for a directory that is a fixed limitation of the NetApp ONTAP filesystem.  [From this knowledge base article](https://now.netapp.com/Knowledgebase/solutionarea.asp?id=ntapcs3039):

> Starting with Data ONTAP 6.5, the
>   maximum number of subdirectories a
>   single directory may have is 99998
>   (100K). Data ONTAP 6.4 and earlier
>   versions were restricted to 65534
>   (64K) subdirectories. This number may
>   not be changed. To understand the
>   reason for this limit, see the section
>   below on hard links and subdirectory
>   implementation.

Comment: This answer is not true anymore, the limits can be changed, see new answers http://serverfault.com/a/591995/10361

Answer (score 7):

There are two limits that you may have hit.

- inodes (unlikely)

  You've consumed all of the available inodes for that volume. You can confirm this with the commands `df -i` and `maxfiles`.
- `maxdirsize` (more likely)

  ONTAP imposes a limit on size of directories. Size being a product of metadata/hardlinks, not file content. This limit defaults (assuming >6.5) to 1% of your system RAM. It does so to ensure that large directories don't impact system performance. Because linear directory scans require directory data structures to be loaded into memory. Quick overview:

  - You can check a directory size with `ls -lkd`.
  - Raising `maxdirsize` for a volume is a bit of a one way operation.
  - Only raise it in small increments.
  - You can't reduce a directory's size by deleting it's contents.
  - I have these two bookmarked links which contain a lot more information.

    - [NOW: What is maxdirsize?](https://now.netapp.com/Knowledgebase/solutionarea.asp?id=kb5052)
    - [Communities: maxdirsize Recommended Setting and Performance Implications](http://communities.netapp.com/thread/2564)

If it's neither of these issues then I'd recommend checking and posting your ONTAP logs.

Comment: Oh thanks, looks my thought on walf.maxdirsize was on the right track maybe, but outdated :-)

Comment: Although that would put the max at 20MB, which is a pretty big directory...

Comment: Nope, its not the dirfilesize, its definitely the number of files...

Comment: 20Mb should give you around 640k files NFS-only files. But I've found that the calculations don't always work out so favourably. Nevertheless, do check `/etc/messages`, because the logs are often helpfully indicative.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to have run out of inodes... within 6 months of moderate usage in an academic research environment I had a system that ran out of the default number of inodes. People can chew up inodes real quick when they do things like store copies of their imap folders in their home directories.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.unixunderground.com/blog/?cat=11

A bit dated, but might be helpful.  I believe the number of files is based on the number of disks/nodes.

Comment: Thats not the issue it seems...

Comment: Good thought though!

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of NetApp (8.1+) you can overwrite the default limits per volume using this command:

```
vol options vol_name maxdirsize 150000
```

To see current settings run

```
vol options vol_name
```

There is no way to change these from the GUI client.